# why does this return undefined - javascript

Tags: javascript

i'm pretty new to js. i'm sorry if this sounds dumb.
but why does the following code return "undefined"

```
function NewPerson(name, age, sex){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.sex = sex;

    this.getName = function(){
        //alert(this.name);
        alert("The age is "+this.age);
    };

}

var obj1 = new NewPerson("Mark",25,"Male");
alert("The age is as follows "+obj1.getName());
```

// output:

The age is 25
The age is as follows undefined

Comment: It only "sounds dumb" if you know the answer :) It's a perfectly legitimate, if beginner, question-don't apologize.

Comment: :) .Thanks again for your reply at such short notice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you don't return anything.

Comment: sorry for being so ridiculous..i cant believe i was so stupid and did not even use any sense.  i got it. thanks

Comment: @Phil I was going to edit, but wanted to given him a chance :) Looks like he's pretty quick, which is cool :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to explixitly return in you function

Following should work

```
function NewPerson(name, age, sex){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.sex = sex;

    this.getName = function(){
        //alert(this.name);
        alert("The age is "+this.age);
    return this.age
    };

}

    var obj1 = new NewPerson("Mark",25,"Male");
    alert("The age is as follows "+obj1.getName());
```

Comment: Of course there's the question of why a function with the name `getName` returns the age.

Answer (score 2):

No one else mentioned it so I will - it is more efficient to put functions that will be the same for all instances on the constructor's prototype. Then you only have one instance of the function that is used by all instances, e.g.

```
function NewPerson(name, age, sex){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.sex = sex;
} 

NewPerson.prototype.getName = function() {
    alert("The age is "+this.age);
    return this.name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get some value from called function you must use

```
return value;
```

So try

```
function NewPerson(name, age, sex){
this.name = name;
this.age = age;
this.sex = sex;

this.getName = function(){
    alert("The age is "+this.age);
    return this.name;
};
}  
var obj1 = new NewPerson("Mark",25,"Male");
alert("The name is as follows "+obj1.getName());
```

will work as you expected.

Answer (score 0):

As stated before, you didn't return anything in `getName`.

It looks like you don't really want to alert age in `getName`. Also, adding `getName` to each instance of the object in the constructor is inefficient. Use the prototype method instead. I am submitting the cleaned-up code for what you are probably going for:

```
    function Person(name, age, sex) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.sex = sex;
    };
    Person.prototype.getName = function() {
        return this.name;
    };
    var obj1 = new Person("Mark",25,"Male");
    alert("The name is: "+obj1.getName());
```

By placing `getName` on the prototype, all instances of Person will have access to the same function, thus saving memory :) By using the statement `this.getName = ...` in the constructor function Person, you are making a new function for each instance of Person.

Comment: Damn near simultaneous post with the same idea.

Comment: Why is there a `NewPerson` and a `Person`?

Answer (score 0):

> @Davenewton 's  answer is correct and while I like it for its
>   straightforwardness, it takes that
>    famous *a-ha!* moment for you to fully
>   realize why. Here's what's really going on:

So to elaborate
If we had something like this:

```js
function i_am(){
  var a = 'very smart person';
  console.log(this.a);
}

var a = 'monkey';
i_am();
```

Depending on what linter or browser you might be using, this might either return

```
> "monkey" // (try the snippet)
```

or also

```
> "monkey"  
> undefined    // check the sreenshot
```

[image]

This is because of one simple reason, best understood if we go step-by-step how compiler "reads" the code.

1. hoist the `function i_am()` declaration to top (`undefined`)
2. hoist the `var a` declaration to top (`undefined`)
3. assign `'monkey'` to variable `a` (now string `"monkey"`)
4. execute/invoke the `i_am()` a function we have pre-declared
5. create a local variable `a` and assign string `"very smart person"`
6. `console.log(this.a)` returns `'monkey'`, because `this` refers to `var`/`property a` (same thing in this case) of the `global` object - call-site is from `global` object : `i_am();`
7. Finish execution - but uh oh! **We executed function and returned no value!**

Now, depending on your environment, either it hides the `undefined` result from you, or it prints it out! Why? Because `function`s are looking to `return` a value. Just like with variable declaration, if you do

```js
var a;
console.log(a);
```

it has not been assigned a value, hence it results after RHS in `undefined`.

Similar principle applies to function, where it's looking to return a value, but it doesn't return anything, hence resulting in `undefined`

---

In other words, **it's not `this` that `return`s `undefined`. It's the invokation of `i_am();` that returns `undefined`!**

Hopefully it's clear to everybody now :)